# How to enable SimpleXML extension in PHP (Gentoo OS)

Tags: php, apache, simplexml, gentoo

I am working on a gentoo server. Currently in PHP, the SimpleXML extension is not enabled. How do I enable this extension ?

The PHP version is 5.2

The configure command has "--disable-simplexml".

Is it possible to use "emerge" package manager to enable this extension ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reemerge php with the 'simplexml' USE flag set. It is on-by-default, so you probably will not have to do anything more than

emerge php -vua

In the case that the 'simplexml' USE flag is not set, add it to your USE= set in /etc/make.conf and then reemerge php using the above command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to recompile PHP.
Also see [this comment on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.installation.php#87954)

Btw. PHP 5.2 is *wayy* out of date, you should consider updating PHP.

Comment: How do i find the path of PHP Source ?

Comment: Do you mean the source code? If yes then on [php.net](http://php.net) of course. Otherwise, let me know what exactly you mean